# Ionic no inicia

Tags: ionic, cordova, rutas

como les va? Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, ya instale ionic con el comando "npm install -g @ionic/cli" tambien instale cordova , pero al ingresar el comando "ionic start" para iniciar y crear un proyecto nuevo me sale un men[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]saje de que "ionic no se reconoce como comando externo ni interno"

Comment: El mensaje dice que no reconoce el comando. Podrías revisar con ``npm list -g --depth=0`` para mostrar una lista de paquetes instalados y verificar la instalación.

Comment: Si estan instalados los paquetes ionic y cordova. ¿Se te ocurre cual puede ser el problema?

Comment: Revisa la ruta de instalación de Node. Podrías abrir una terminal y teclear ``set`` dar Enter y observar el nombre de las variables del sistema. También podrías abrir una terminal en la ruta de instalación de Node y ejecutar el comando. Otra forma es reinstalar ionic, primero desinstalar ``npm uninstall -g ionic`` después volver a instalar  ``npm install -g ionic``